# displaying correlation values in seaborn scatter plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

I'm using seaborn's lmplot/regplot to visualize scatter plots.  I want to be able to look at the scatter plots and visually see if there is a "significant" relationship between x and y.   Labeling the regression line with its correlation value (i.e., pearson's r), and/or its slope and significance, would be perfect.  I don't think this can be eye-balled from the the confidence intervals automatically displayed around the regression lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want this the `jointplot` function will add [correlation information](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/regression_marginals.html), but it's not in `lmplot` for two reasons. First, I think it's distracting and one should focus on understanding the relationship visually rather than relying on the crutch of a p value. Second, `lmplot` is meant to be (or is often) used with multiple variables where the fit statistic is undefined in the sense that you might want to know how well the full model fits the data or how well the model fits when conditioned on various other variables. Moreover, an R^2 for a "full" model fit wouldn't actually correspond to what you see in the plot, where relationships are conditioned on different levels of the variables but do not show partial regressions with the other levels.